# Complexity time building an Iterator

Tags: java, data-structures, time-complexity

I have this code

```
public AvlTree(int[] data) {
    for (int val : data) {
        add(val);
    }
}
public AVLTree(AVLTree avlTree) {
    for (int val : avlTree) {
        add(val);
    }
}
```

where AVLTree implements Iterable. The first constructor runs in O(n log n),add takes O(log n) ,and I wanted to ask: is it the same for second constructor or does it take more time to make the iterator than iterate through it?
iterator :

```
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return node != null;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Node cur = node;
        node = successor(node);
        return cur.getKey();
    }
```

successor runs in logn also

Comment: This depends on the implementation of `iterator()` method in `AVLTree`. We cannot tell you much more without its source code. Usually, iterator creation is cheap and O(1), though.

Comment: the time to create your iterator will depend on your implementation but generally it shouldn't take more than finding the *first* element, which is either root (-> O(1)) or the min/max element (-> O(log n)), depending on your traversal scheme. iterating through all elements is still O(n) so there's no asymptotic difference between the two (the iterator one will have a constant overhead).

Answer (score 1):

Both the constructors should take the same time O(n) as you are iterating the whole data in both instances.

Even though add() method takes only O(n log n), the fact that you are iterating the data makes it O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Iterating the tree is still `O(n)` (just like the array) unless the implementation specifies otherwise.

So the overall complexity remains `O(n log n)`.